# We have two networks, In Domain A user will be created, but the same user also able to login in Domain B network

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller, subdomain, entra-domain-services

I need clarification on DC's, I have implemented some setting but its not working.  Pls clarify..Thanks in Advance,

Network:
We have two network with two different DC's. DC1 is Active Directory 2012 and DC2 Active Directory 2016.
We are merging our plant.

Requirment:
Normally we will have different user for different DC's, because of merging plant we need to create common user they can access both network Domain PC.
User need to create in DC1 and he can access the DC1 PC's and DC2 PC's. But when he login in DC1 network different policies will apply and when he login in DC2 network differnt polices need to apply.

Implementation :

- Created DNS conditional Forwarders b/w DC's.
- I have created Trust b/w two domain in TWO way access.
- DC2 is given delegate control to DC1 user.
- User of DC1 not able to access the DC2 pc.
- DC1 : XXX.AP.XO.COM
- DC2 : ABC.LOCAL

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "delegate control"? What tool did you use to give control over what objects? Also, is there a trust established between the two domains?

Comment: In active directory user and computer there is an option Delegation control : we can grant users permission to mangae users, groups, computer and OU, and other objects stored in Active directory Domain Services. As i mentioned above Trust was established b/w domains..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user from DC1 is able to reach and resolve a DNS name from DC2, then you have an issue with permissions. You would need firstly, to allow user from DC1 to operate on DC2.

Check that PCs on DC2 has security group (with user from DC1) allowed to login.